# export xlwt to open an excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

i am using "import xlwt" to create new excel sheet but it is throwing the following error?

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xl.txt", line 1, in 
    import xlwt
ImportError: No module named xlwt**

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install package xlwt.
You will get the package [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt)